# ubuntu 13.10 can't detect windows 7 and NTFS partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 13.10, windows-7

I have already windows -7  installed on my PC. and I want to install ubuntu 13.10 alongside windows-7 . but while installing ubuntu, it doen't give me option to install ubuntu alongside windows and also can't detect windows and partition too...
what I can do now ???
sry for my poor english....

Answer (score 1):

Is your drive partitioned correctly?

If not here's the solution that may help you:

### Method 1 (with Gparted):

- Boot into Ubuntu liveCD and click 'Try Ubuntu'
- Then go to the `GParted` application
- Shrink the Windows volume, for an example see below (or [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLQH7.png)):

  ---

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLQH7.png]

---

- After that create a partition for Linux with EXT2, EXT3 or EXT4 partition (I recommend EXT4)

  *Then reboot (restart) , and you will see the installation option, 'Install Ubuntu'.

---

### Method 2 (using Ubuntu LiveCD):

- When Ubuntu installation shows the option 'Something Else' click it
- Then click 'Advanced Partition Tool' and shrink Windows volume
- Create one partition with EXT2 / EXT3 / EXT4 partition in the free space.
- After that you will see the button install now enabled, click it.

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps ::

> +In windows right click  "my computer" > manage > disk management
>
> +shrink some unused free space for ubuntu (Based on your usage)
>
> +insert ubuntu CD / USB drive
>
> +Restart
>
> +Boot from CD/USB by pressing F12
>
> +Select Ubuntu in boot options
>
> +Click "Try Ubuntu"
>
> +After it opens , Click on Install Ubuntu
>
> +select language > turn on internet for updates(recommended) > plugin to power source
>
> +Here if it don't show the option "alongside windows" , click "Something Else"
>
> +Now you have to make three partitions as follows ,

## 1. root for all user installed packages (mount to '/' with ext4 filesystem)

## 2. Home for all user download files and media (mount to '/home' with ext4)

## 3. Swap memory, probably half of your RAM size is enough (mount to swap)

(For all three choosing primary or logical is doesn't matter, Ubuntu don't care)
You are done now

> +Click Next > Set Date and Time settings
>
> +Sit and Relax until it finishes the installation
>
> +Restart when it is done
>
> +Now , If windows don't show up in the boot :
>
> +In ubuntu , goto terminal and install boot-repair using,

~/sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

~/sudo apt-get update

~/sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

> +In boot-repair click advanced options > other options
>
> +make sure Repair windows boot files option is checked
>
> +click apply
>
> +Restart
> You will have grub menu with both ubuntu and windows during booting

<< If ubuntu don't show up in the boot :
click F12 , and select ubuntu from the boot options displayed
then install the boot-repair from the same process above. >>

Hope this helps, Thank You!

Comment: Thankx bro ....but it showing me entire disk empty where as i have 4 partition....ubuntu not detecting partition

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and am currently working to fix it. I found that you can have no more than 4 primary partitions on any given drive. If your drive has 4 partitions already, make sure that when you attempt to partition the drive as shown above that you select logical for each one, or if you can make one primary, try to make a single EXT4 /boot primary partition that has just 500MB of space (1/2GB). Make sure the /home partition is th largest as it will hold all your files and data. the / partition, or 'root' partition, need not be larger than 6000MB (6GB) as the root is designed to fit on a 5.7GB DVD. Again, assure that all but the /boot partition are set as logical instead of primary.

Comment: I don't think this is because of the primary partition limit. The installer still would show the options and then report an error during partitioning.